# How I can output a constant text in struct when call cout?

Tags: c++, struct, operator-overloading, cout

I have this struct:

```
struct sample {
  int x;
};
```

and then I have this overload of operator<<:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(const std::ostream &os, const sample &s) {
  if (s.x == 0)
    return os << "zero";
  else
    return os << "not zero";
}
```

main:

```
int main() {
  sample sam;
  sam.x = 0;
  std::cout << sam << std::endl;
  sam.x = 1;
  std::cout << sam << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But the compiler gives me this error:
[Complile Error](https://pastebin.com/dsfbLw58)

What can I do?

Comment: Remove the `const` from `const std::ostream &os` in the operator signature.

Comment: Also, you need to `return os;` at the end of the routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right except for a small error in your operator signature:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(const std::ostream &os, const sample &s)
//                       ^^^^^ Problem
```

You mark the output stream as `const` but then modify it inside the function:

```
os << "zero";
```

and

```
os << "not zero";
```

Because

[`std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>::operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) is not `const`.

---

So, remove that `const` and the code will work.